# count packets received from running tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I am using tcpdump to check if any packets are being received, while I am getting the packets from continuous listening on the port, I want a condition that has a count and each time a packets received, it is added to the count, I am using bash scripting to do this, any thoughts please?

I get packets, but I don't get a count until I ctrl + c out of the continuous command

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and filter there? Honest question if this is about debugging only.

If this is however about counting packages to do some action in your own code using tcpdump, you'd either have to:

- parse the output of tcpdump where a `newline` equals one package until the output isn't prefixed by the datetime.
- create a file after `n` packages using the `-c` switch and await the termination of tcpdump

For further reference, see [man tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html#lbAE).

In any case, I'd strongly advocate for Wireshark if you just need this for debugging.

Comment: I am trying to maintain a process in the background which is listening on a port and making sure packets are received from that port, else, to run some scripts, sort of like automation

Comment: @newNodeJS-er So it's some sort of monitoring? I'd rather advice then to check whether the port is in use and implement some sort of health check in your application which you can trigger periodically. That's a lot easier and probably way less headache in the end.

Comment: Awesome that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!